# Saving A Character that you pop out of a char vector

Tags: c++

Im trying to save a char that im going to pop out of the char vector can you do that? If so how?

[image: ****]

Comment: Can you please write your code here instead of the image?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the actual code (not an image) and to describe what you're trying to achieve (and which errors you get). _"Saving a character..."_ is not helpful. BTW `std::stoi()` does NOT want `char` as input but `std::string` (or `std::wstring`)

Comment: You are saving the char that you pop out of the vector. Your error is that you are using `stoi` incorrectly. `stoi` is for strings not for characters, strings and characters are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the character. This code

```
char char_toInt = vect[vect.size() - 1];
```

saves the character perfectly well. Not sure why you thought that was incorrect.

The mistake is the next line

```
int new_int = stoi(char_toInt);
```

Instead do it like this

```
int new_int = char_toInt - '0';
```

`stoi` is for a `string` and you have a `char`. These are not the same thing, and C++ is fussy about *types*.

Instead to convert a digit char to it's integer value just subtract `'0'` from the char. All chars are represented as integers internally (lookup ASCII if you are interested in the how this might be done). Subtracting `'0'` gives you the difference between the integer corresponding to your digit and the integer corresponding to `'0'`. Since the integers corresponding to the digits are guaranteed to be sequential this gives you the value of your digit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write something like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v;

    v.push_back('a');
    v.push_back('b');
    v.push_back('c');

    std::cout << v.back() << std::endl;
    v.pop_back();

    std::cout << v.back() << std::endl;
    v.pop_back();

    std::cout << v.back() << std::endl;
    v.pop_back();

    return 0;
}
```

which would produce an output of

```
c
b
a
```

Alternatively, you can also use a queue:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::queue<char> q;

    q.push('a');
    q.push('b');
    q.push('c');

    std::cout << q.front() << std::endl;
    q.pop();

    std::cout << q.front() << std::endl;
    q.pop();

    std::cout << q.front() << std::endl;
    q.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

which would produce an output of:

```
a
b
c
```

Or, alternatively, you can use a stack:

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stack<char> s;

    s.push('a');
    s.push('b');
    s.push('c');

    std::cout << s.top() << std::endl;
    s.pop();

    std::cout << s.top() << std::endl;
    s.pop();

    std::cout << s.top() << std::endl;
    s.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

which would produce an output of:

```
c
b
a
```